# NullPointerException on starting application

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I tired to start my Activity (declared in AndroidManifest) , but then I saw that error(s) :

```
08-11 16:04:05.952: E/AndroidRuntime(815): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-11 16:04:05.952: E/AndroidRuntime(815): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.radzik.devadmin/com.radzik.devadmin.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-11 16:04:05.952: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
08-11 16:04:05.952: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
08-11 16:04:05.952: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
08-11 16:04:05.952: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
08-11 16:04:05.952: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-11 16:04:05.952: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-11 16:04:05.952: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
08-11 16:04:05.952: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-11 16:04:05.952: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-11 16:04:05.952: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
08-11 16:04:05.952: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-11 16:04:05.952: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-11 16:04:05.952: E/AndroidRuntime(815): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-11 16:04:05.952: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at com.radzik.devadmin.MainActivity.ustawWidokMain(MainActivity.java:107)
08-11 16:04:05.952: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at com.radzik.devadmin.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
08-11 16:04:05.952: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
08-11 16:04:05.952: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
08-11 16:04:05.952: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
08-11 16:04:05.952: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  ... 11 more
```

That means that error is on 107th line :

```
private void ustawWidokMain()
{
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button b01 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.main_pass);
    Button b02 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.main_wipes);
    Button b03 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.main_camera);
    Button b04 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.main_enctpyion);
    Button b05 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.main_b1);
    if(!pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA) && !pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FRONT)) // there's error
    {
        b03.setEnabled(false);
    }
```

I don't know why I have that error. That method is called like that :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        /* Some code has been removed */
        if(dcm.isAdminActive(c))
        ustawWidokMain();
```

Comment: Where/how is `pm` initialized?

Comment: Print the value of pm before the if statement.  What is its value?

Comment: Is `pm` initialized in `onCreate()` and before calling this function?

Comment: **Can you tell me why did you downvote my question ? Every issue, programming welcome on Stack Overflow.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would venture to guess that you are initializing `pm` outside of `onCreate()`. This would try initializing it before you actually had a `Context` and it would return `null`. You need to do this inside of `onCreate()` and before calling the function that uses it.

```
PackageManager pm;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    pm = getPackageManager();

    /* Some code has been removed */
    if(dcm.isAdminActive(c))
    ustawWidokMain();
```

Anything that needs a `Context` inside of an `Activity` needs to be initialized, at the earliest, in `onCreate()` since the `Activity` and its `Context` aren't initialized before this.

Comment: He said: `pm is PackageManager and is declared in onCreate() as pm = getPackageManager()` so i don't think that is the problem

Comment: @StefanoMunarini I missed where the OP said it was initialized in `onCreate()` but the answer was accepted so maybe it wasn't before calling the method that uses it.

Comment: Wrong accepted, because he didn't declare permissions, and told me the above!

Comment: @StefanoMunarini if it was a permission issue then it should throw an error stating something about the permission, not `NPE`

Comment: He hadn't declared permissions before posting this question!

Comment: @StefanoMunarini right but that wouldn't cause a `NPE` but would be a separate issue. Probably why your answer was upvoted. However, that wouldn't solve the current issue

Comment: Ok, it did resolved, you're right! But him said (look at the comment at my question) that he initialized `pm` into onCreate(). That's the matter!

Comment: @StefanoMunarini I understand that he said that. I didn't see it when I posted the answer, just that it was not initialized but not where. Since it was accepted, that's why I said, "...so maybe it wasn't before calling the method that uses it."

Answer (score 1):

Have you declared permissions in Manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

And what is `pm`? Where do you have instatiate it? Seems you are missing to.

Comment: `pm` is PackageManager and is declared in onCreate() as `pm = getPackageManager()`

Comment: What about permissions?

Comment: I hadn't decelerated it. Now I will test with that permissions

Comment: But Activity inherits of Context. Why should I write like that ?

Comment: Sorry, i've deleted it! That was the same

Comment: You said you declared it into onCreate() !! Why accept another answer when you did it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It means you did not declare or initialize the object in this ustawWidokMain method. Please recheck or debug to which line gives you error.

Comment: No, `pm` is PackageManager and is declared in onCreate() as `pm = getPackageManager()`

Comment: Must have a targetSdk >= 9 defined in the AndroidManifest. and permission required.

Comment: PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager(); try with this and also check the Camera.getNumberOfCameras() it gives you number of camera in your device